# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> xmlServletPath in servlet mapping

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, illegalargumentexception, url-pattern

When I start Tomcat v7.0 Server from Servers tab in Eclipse, a problem occurred message box appears saying:

> Starting Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost has encountered a problem.
>
> Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

I am a beginner in this area and searched for every similar question on stackoverflow, tried the solutions given by others, but none worked. What can I do to solve the issue?

web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<web-app xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ; xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" ; xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" ; id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"> 

<display-name>SimpleServletProject</display-name> 

<servlet> <servlet-name>xmlServlet</servlet-name> 

          <servlet-class>org.swechchha.XmlServlet</servlet-class>

 </servlet> 

<servlet-mapping>

     <servlet-name>xmlServlet</servlet-name>

     <url-pattern>xmlServletPath</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>   

 </web-app> –
```

Logs are here:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> xmlServletPath in servlet mapping
```

Comment: If there is any logs written in console please attach them

Comment: There should be a details button below the message showing you some more information. Please post that here

Comment: I have edited my question and included logs. Please have a look. And details button showed following text: Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost (2) failed to start.

Comment: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid xmlServletPath in servlet mapping ", that reads to me like there is a mistake in the web.xml.

Comment: web.xml is<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SimpleServletProject</display-name>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>xmlServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.swechchha.XmlServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>xmlServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>xmlServletPath</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>

Comment: Any reason why upon seeing that posting XML as a comment is not a good idea you are not fixing your mistake and adding it to your question instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution. did a silly mistake in web.xml file. missed a '/' .It must be

```
    <url-patterns>/xmlServletPath</url-patterns>
```

If still the server doesn't start, it may be it needs more time, increase the timeout entry from default '45' by double clicking your server in 'Servers' tab.

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't work for you?

To resolve this issue, you have to delete the .snap file located in the directory :

```
<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources
```

After deleting this file, you could start Eclipse with no problem.

Comment: no..it didn't work..i deleted snap file

Comment: Please provide more details.. And i will be able to help. Can you send the error details?